How to spawn part 35 studs in front of player, facing same direction as player?
I'm trying to spawn a wall in front of the player, 35 studs out, and perpendicular to their view (so the wall is flat in front of them). When I spawn the wall, it doesn't show up in the correct spot and I'm not sure why. Please see this video for example.
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = player.Character
local rootPart = char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
local wall = workspace.FX:WaitForChild("Wall")

-- Note that the wall is cloned into the FX folder in a different script.

wall.Position = rootPart.CFrame.LookVector.Unit * 35 + rootPart.Position


You can do this by using the CFrame.new(Position, LookAt) function.
-- // Services
local Players = game:GetService("Players");

-- // Variables
local client = Players.LocalPlayer;
local Character = client.Character;
local Root = Character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart");
local Wall = workspace.FX:WaitForChild("Wall");

-- CFrame.new(position (Vector3), lookAt (Vector3))
Wall.CFrame = CFrame.new( (Root.Position + Root.CFrame.LookVector * 35), Root.Position );

